# How to get neatly formatted date parameters in SSRS, using underlying date datatype?

Tags: sql, parameters, ssrs-2008, report, date

I'm generating some MI reports in SSRS that use underlying tables with a date and some factual information, for example:

```
RiskID int
DateRaised date
Severity varchar(30)
Title varchar(200)
```

I've created a report with parameters @StartDate, @EndDate, and @Severity. I want the user to be able to select the dates in the form "2006 January" or perhaps "2010 Q4". I can do this by having a dataset for the parameters to be e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME("Year", DateRaised) + ' Q' + DATENAME("Quarter", 
DateRaised) AS Date FROM tbRisks ORDER BY Date
```

However this ends up sorting like so:

```
2003 April
2003 August
2003 December
```

etc.(since it is sorted as a string).

it also means I can't use the parameters in the main report dataset to limit the results by date since they are strings.

Does anybody know how I can allow user-friendly inputs (sorted by date) for the parameters based on the range of dates in the table, whilst still allow limiting by date range in the main report dataset?

Many thanks!

Bob

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DATENAME("Year", DateRaised) + ' Q' + DATENAME("Quarter", DateRaised) AS Date,
  DATEPART("Year", DateRaised) AS Sort1,
  DATEPART("Quarter", DateRaised) AS Sort2,
FROM tbRisks
ORDER BY Sort1, Sort2
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT
  DATENAME("Year", DateRaised) + ' Q' + DATENAME("Quarter", DateRaised) AS Date
FROM tbRisks
GROUP BY
  DATENAME("Year", DateRaised) + ' Q' + DATENAME("Quarter", DateRaised)
ORDER BY MIN(DateRaised)
```

Answer (score 0):

If DateRaised is in date format, then just change the end of your statement to

```
ORDER BY DateRaised
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers Guys,

I ended up adding two extra 'columns' generated from the source data, that I could use in the Report Arguments, e.g. Supposing the user selects Start Date = "May 2008" End Date = "Feb 2009". What's really needed in the query is start date of 2008-05-01 00:00:01 to 2009-02-28 23:59:59, this will do this on the fly and use user friendly dates:

```
Select DISTINCT 
'YearMonth' =
  CASE
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 01 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Jan'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 02 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Feb'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 03 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Mar'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 04 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Apr'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 05 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' May'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 06 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Jun'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 07 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Jul'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 08 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Aug'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 09 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Sep'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 10 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Oct'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 11 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Nov'
     WHEN MONTH(dtwhen) = 12 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+' Dec'
     ELSE LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dtwhen, 20),4)+'Jan' -- DPT
  END,
  CAST(CAST(YEAR(dtwhen) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(dtwhen) AS varchar) + '-01 00:00:01' AS DateTime) AS MonthBegin,
--Add a date column storing the exact date at the end of the selected month
-- E.g. Jan 2004 becomes Jan 29th 23:59:59
-- It basically adds 1 month to the exact beginning of next month, then rolls back 2 seconds..
DATEADD(SECOND,-2,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CAST(CAST(YEAR(dtwhen) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(dtwhen) AS varchar) + '-01 00:00:01' AS DateTime))) AS MonthEnd
FROM Feedback
ORDER BY MonthBegin DESC
```

Key point to note is in SSRS you can display the varchar field to the user ("May 2005") and use the other, calculated, underlying datetime value (2005-05-01 00:00:01) in your query.